# Shade/Fill between Arbitrary Matplotlib Region Based On Axes, Not Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Is it possible to fill between arbitrary regions of a chart not based upon the plotted data but the x-axis range?

In the time series plot below, I shade the region between 8pm and 8am using this fill_between call:

```py
ax3.fill_between(d[0], 0, ax3.get_ylim()[1], where=fill, facecolor=face_color )
```

Where `fill` is determined based upon the data being recorded during those hours:

```py
fill = [False if dt.time(8,0,0) < t.time() < dt.time(20,0,0) else True for t in d[0]]
```

This works fine for the first two shaded regions.

[image]

The issue is that sometimes, the recorded data will not be present for those hours and so the shaded region is too small and does not represent the appropriate hours (see the 3rd shaded region in the chart)

I realise I could do this by creating another data set with the appropriate x value range and then set it to invisible but I wanted to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct an array of `datetime` objects which span the same range as your `x` data and use that to populate the `fill` array,

```py
import numpy as np
# ...
fill = [False if dt.time(8, 0, 0) < t.time() < dt.time(20, 0, 0) else True for t in 
        np.arange(x[0], x[-1]+60, 60, dtype='datetime64').astype(dt.datetime)]
```

Complete example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
x = np.arange('2020-04-03T00:00Z', '2020-04-05T00:30Z', np.random.randint(50, 70), 
              dtype='datetime64[m]')
x = np.delete(x, np.s_[4:10])
x = np.delete(x, np.s_[25:32])
y = np.sin(np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, len(x))*2 + np.random.random(len(x)) - 0.5)
plt.plot(x, y)

dx = np.arange(x[0], x[-1]+60, 60, dtype='datetime64[m]').astype(dt.datetime)
fill = [False if dt.time(8, 0, 0) < t.time() < dt.time(20, 0, 0) else True for t in dx]
plt.fill_between(dx, plt.ylim()[0], plt.ylim()[1], where=fill, fc='grey', alpha=0.2)

plt.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately, it does not work: the fill array must be the same dimensions as the data to be plotted. Creating a datetime array of the same length and range results in miss-alignment between the data x-axis and the fill x-axis. I would work with a much more elaborate fill array creation mechanism but the law of diminishing returns would say its not worth the effort.

Comment: @DaveB I have edited the code in my answer to correct for the issue you've raised. The code should now work correctly as long as the array from which `dx` is derived is sorted earliest to latest.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still exists but is not present in your example as x and dx are exactly equal. As my data is time-series, it is aperiodically spaced. You can reproduce by doing something like `x = np.arange('2020-04-03T00:00Z', '2020-04-05T00:30Z', np.random.randint(50, 70), dtype='datetime64[m]')`

Comment: @DaveB Very well, I have updated my example to use aperiodic data, and also placed some gaps in it. As you can see, the regions without data are shaded properly. I hope this is helpful to you

Comment: Thanks William but the problem still exists. Please compare x, dx, and Fill and you will see that in some cases, where Fill is true, x is not between the appropriate hours.

Comment: Forgive me, I was plotting x in fill_bewteen instead of dx. Your answer is correct. Thanks for the help